# Django: template for form and list of objects on the same page

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to set up a template for a page that has the following behavior. Initially, it will contain an unfilled form and a list of all objects of a certain model. The user may then enter information into the form, and upon hitting submit, the list of models shown will be filtered to reflect the submitted request as appropriate.

I believe I have the logic of all of this set up correctly; this is the view for this page:

```
def search(request):

    objs = Area.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = AreaForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_bound and form.is_valid():

            # check if requested number of chairs/tables/etc
            # is at most the amount present    
            # or skip if blank
            def check(area, key, val):
                attr_val = getattr(area, key)
                attr_val is None or attr_val >= val

            # filter out those objects which don't have the criteria
            for key, val in form.cleaned_data.items:
                objs = [area for area in objs if check(area, key, val)]

    else:
        form = AreaForm()

    return render(request, 'SpotMe/search.html', {'form' : form, 'objs': objs})
```

So now (I believe) I just need to set up the template html. What I have so far is this:

```
<form action="" method="GET">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Send message" />
</form>
```

But I'm kind of at a loss as to how to move forward. I would greatly appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your `objs` contains the correct items, you just add something like

```
{% for obj in objs %}
<li>{{ obj }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

after closing your `</form>` tag